# Make a controllers model available to the ApplicationController before it's loaded in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying get access to a controller needed by my ApplicationController (Application needs Practice), however the PracticeController is only available after the resource has been loaded through it's respective route-url visit.
How, can I make sure the PracticeController and it's content/model is available at all times?
To be specific, I need my flashcardArray to be available throughout my application and at all times, even when the Practice-route hasn't been visited, thus loaded yet.
Thanks for any help!

Here is my code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('signup');
    this.resource('login');
    this.resource('profile');
    this.resource('practice');
    this.resource('overview');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    controllerName: 'application',
    model: function () {}
});

App.PracticeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('flashcards');
    }
});

//ApplicationController
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['practice'],
    flashcardArray: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.practice.flashcardArray'),
    currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('model'),
    isLoggedIn: false
    }
});

//PracticeController
App.PracticeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    flashcardArray: Ember.computed.alias('model'),
    currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentUser')
    }
});

// Practice template feeded into an outlet of the application template
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="practice">
    <div class="content-padded">
        {{#each object in flashcardArray}}
            <div class="card_wrapper">
            <p><h1>{{{object.num_reference}}}</h1><p>
            <p>PinYin: {{{object.mandarin}}}</p>
            <p>def: {{object.definition}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you have data you need throughout the application, regardless of the user's active route, you probably need to return it as the `ApplicationRoute`:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return {
            user: this.store.find('user'),
            flashcards: this.store.find('flashcards')
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, steve thanx for your answer, I thought of this, however I thought there might be a cleaner solution since user should be handled by a ObjectController and flashcards by a ArrayController. I'm not too sure tho, maybe that's no problem at all. What do you think? Tnx again.